# Groovy clibuilder only show first invalid option

Tags: groovy

When 'stopAtNonOption' is false, groovy will tell you the first option that is unknown. Is there anyway to list all the unknown options instead just the first one?

```
$ ./some_cli_program --knownOption someValue --unknown1 --unknown2 someOtherValue
```

Actual

```
error: unrecoqnized option: --unknown1
```

expected

```
error: unrecoqnized options: --unknown1 --unknown2
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a decent "usage" message is usually good enough. Default behavior is to throw exception on first unrecognised token.

You could customize your parser.   Sample below

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
import org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException
import org.codehaus.groovy.cli.GroovyPosixParser

def cli = new CliBuilder(usage: 'myprog', stopAtNonOption: false)
cli.a("option1")
def unknowns = [];
cli.parser = new GroovyPosixParser() {
    @Override
    protected void processOption(String arg, ListIterator iter) throws ParseException {
        try {
            super.processOption(arg, iter)
        }
        catch (UnrecognizedOptionException specialE) {
            unknowns.push(arg);
        }
    }

}

def options = cli.parse(args)
//on error cli.usage()
if (!unknowns.isEmpty()) {
    println("had unknown options")
    unknowns.each {println it}
    cli.usage()
}

//cli.usage() is probably better and enough
```

Comment: Sometimes the people make some typo and it can be hard to find the actual  errors especially when there are many arguments.